# How to update the firmware of Jackal j100 to ROS2?

Tags: ros2, installation, jackal

I try to update my jackal to ROS2 humble. I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/ros/installation/robot), but did not find the corresponding installation package or the corresponding burning script

```
jackal@jackal-desktop: $
jackal@jackal-desktop: $ sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-clearpath-firmware[sudo] password for jackal:
Hit:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB] 
Hit:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease 
Hit:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB] 
Hit:6 https://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/ubuntu jamny InRelease Fetched 229 kB in 2s (104 kB/s) Reading package lists... Done
W: https://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/ubuntu/dists/janmy/InRelease: Ke y is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECAClTION section in apt-key(8) for details. Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree,.. Done Reading state information,,, Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-clearpath-firnware
```

and

```
jackal@jackal-desktop:-$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
ros2 run clearpath_firmware flash ings 
Package 'clearpath_firmware' not found
```

What should I do to solve the problrm?

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo in your sources list for `apt`:

```
Hit:6 https://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/ubuntu jamny InRelease Fetched 229 kB in 2s (104 kB/s) Reading package lists... Done
W: https://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/ubuntu/dists/janmy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECAClTION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

It should be [`jammy`](https://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/ubuntu/dists/jammy/).

Comment: I have corrected the typo but still the same error. :(

Comment: Did you run `apt update` afterwards? The log above also shows `ros-humble-clearpath-firnware`- another typo in `firmware` which seems to be corrected in your post?!